# Can I use C++ with UDK?

Tags: c++, unreal-development-kit

Can I use C++ with UDK? I know they mention unrealscript on their page but I've also heard that C++ can be used instead, is that so?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206681/what-language-is-used-when-programming-in-unreal-development-kit

Comment: As soon as one question gets closed, you open essentially the same one again. This is so unreal!

Comment: @JerryCoffin I asked once this question, and people closed it as "Not real question". So I re-worded it to show, that indeed, that is real question and the answer to it isn't obvious at all.

Comment: Have you tried asking the folks at Unreal?

Comment: @JerryCoffin and what's really unreal is the arrogance and ignorance of some people here. How this question could be closed as Not a real question? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. If you use the free version of UDK you can't code the game in C++, but you can include self written DLLs which can be written in C++.

If you become a licensee you get the C++ source code of the unreal engine 3 and then are able to program in C++.

But getting the source code is very expensive, several grand if I recall correctly, so you are probably stuck with UnrealScript for the majority of your time.

Comment: thanks for answering to "Not a real question" ;). In that case (being stuck with UnityScript) I better forget about it and move to OGRE. I simply cannot sacrifize performance, that's why I also didn't consider Unity. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @SmallB I'm sad to see that during the last *two years* you are as closeminded as you were, and haven't learned anything. Considering the fact that Unity 5 will have, among other really impressive features, a GI module, for example, your pet hate is obviously inappropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

More information about how use DLL:
[Calling DLLs from UnrealScript (DLLBind)](http://udn.epicgames.com/Three/DLLBind.html)

Answer (score 0):

Unreal Engine 4 was released recently for 20$/month + 5% of profits, and you get access to its source code which you can compile with your code together.

However, you won't find the UnrealScript component, the only scripting solution available is the GUI-based Kismet-like thingy.